# Include dll's in WiX msi base Installer

Tags: dll, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5, wix3.6

I am currently making an Outlook addin in Visual Studio 2012,
i create an Installer for my project, but in order for my addin to work on my clients computers i also need to add the SharePoint Foundation (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786) dll’s,
but when I try to add them from my C:\Windows\assembly folder to the WiX msi base installer Project\References - (by right clicking and pressing add Reference), I get the following error “A reference to [filepath] could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid WiX reference.“
Do you know what I can do ?
thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the files to Product.wxs - see http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_learning.htm . You only add .wixlib and other projects via references.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but how do i add it there, when i open the wxs file, all i see is Code, i try to right click it but there is no "add dll" Option (I'm a terrible beginner i know, sorry :))
again, thanks for your help

Comment: Does anybody else know an Answer?

Comment: The WiX Visual Studio plugin isn't point-and-click - you have to write code to add files. e.g.:

<Component>
  <File Source="application.exe"/>
</Component>
<Component>
  <File Source="application_lib.dll"/>
</Component>

Comment: do i have to include the dll's in any Folder (bin\debug) or (Obj\Debug) if i want to use them ?

Comment: No, you can use whatever path you need. e.g.:

<File Source="C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll"/>

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to use a WiX 3.7 Bootstrapper project. The bootstrapper engine is often called "Burn" so you might see that in discussions.

A bootstrapper project allows you to install dependencies using their own installers, such as the "SharePoint Foundation 2010 Client Object Model Redistributable" you linked to. A nice example of a bootstrapper is the WiX 3.7 installer itself but most projects can be much simpler.

Installing dependencies using vendor provided installers has the advantage of avoiding having to re-implement any necessary logic yourself and allows them to managed and upgraded by the user.